# Manually running jar packaged by Gradle's application plugin

Tags: java, jar, gradle, executable-jar

I created a simple gradle project which includes the application plugin. I ran the distZip task to create a zip of all the jars. Below is the code I used:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

project(':Module') {
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.sample.HelloWorld'
        }
    }
}

dependencies{
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

mainClassName = "com.sample.HelloWorld"
```

**com.sample.HelloWorld.java**

```
package com.sample;

import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime();
        System.out.println("The current local time is: " + currentTime);
    }
}
```

After running the distZip task, I unzip the generated build/distribution/Module-1.0.zip archive which has the following directory structure:

```
Module-1.0
|__bin
|__lib
     |__Module-1.0.jar
     |__joda-time-2.7.jar
```

Within the lib directory, I tried the command:

```
java com.sample.HelloWorld -cp Module-1.0.jar;joda-time-2.7.jar
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sample.HelloWorld
```

Then I tried:

```
java -jar Module-1.0.jar -cp joda-time-2.7.jar
```

Which gave the output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.noClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/LocalTime...
```

I made sure that in my Manifest.MF file, the Main Class attribute is set to com.sample.HelloWorld, so my question is why does running the `java` command lead to a 'no main class found' error but using the `java -jar` command does not lead to that error?

Also, why is it that Java cannot find the `joda-time-2.7.jar` dependency when I run the `java -jar` command?

I know that you can run the program using the `gradlew run` command -- I tried that and it works perfectly. I am just very curious as to why running traditional java commands do not work.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do. You should use a fatjar where a Jar is created will its dependencies self contained. Something very similar to the distzip just that.. it generates a fatjar with manifest.
Check out [https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin](https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin). It provides you with a very simple gradle task to generate a fatjar.

Comment: @TamLe, if any response answers the question and solves the problem, accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
java -cp Module-1.0.jar:joda-time-2.7.jar:. com.sample.HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command line arguments to java are wrong.  You need to specify the `-cp` parameter before `-jar`.  After the argument to `-jar` everything else is command line arguments to your main class.  So what you want is this:

```
$ java -cp joda-time-2.7.jar-jar Module-1.0.jar
```

Also, you don't need to do this at all, the Grade application plugin will have built you a shell script (*nix systems) and .bat file (windows) to launch your program with, so if you're on *nix, do this instead:

```
$ Module-1.0/bin/<name_of_the_script_here>
```